# vb.net chart using data from excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to just do a simple example before I do a more advanced project and I cant figure out how to use excel data from cells in a chart in vb.net. When I look it up online all I can find is database to vb.net or from vb.net to excel chart. Was going off of this for awhile but none of it is working http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/18/charting-with-vb-net-2010/

Then I tried the below code with no luck, Get run time error converting range to string

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
Dim appXL As Excel.Application
Dim wbsXL As Excel.Workbooks
Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
Dim Rangex As Excel.Range
Dim Rangey As Excel.Range
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = True
    wbsXL = appXL.Workbooks
    wbXL = wbsXL.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data.xlsx")

    Rangey = wbXL.Range("A1:A2")
    Rangex = wbXL.Range("B1:B2")

    With chtTest
        .Series("Series1").YValueMembers = Rangey
        .Series("Series1").XValueMember = Rangex

    End With
End Sub
End Class
```

Can anyone show me a basic example using 2 cells for the x and 2 cells for the y axis data.

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand what you are asking.  I was not able to get your example to work.  Therefore, I just used half the code from this page and half the code from the other page and I got something to work.  Yet, because I could not get your code to run I am not sure if this is what you are asking for.
    'http://ask.brothersoft.com/how-to-use-an-excel-insertable-object-in-visual-basic-160217.html
    'http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_create_chart.htm

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click

```
    Dim XLSApp As New Excel.Application
    XLSApp.Visible = True
    Dim XLSWbks As Excel.Workbooks = XLSApp.Workbooks
    Dim XLSWbk As Excel.Workbook = XLSWbks.Add
    Dim XLSShts As Excel.Sheets = XLSWbk.Worksheets
    Dim XLSSht As Excel.Worksheet = XLSShts("Sheet1")
    XLSSht.Range("A1").Value = "1"
    XLSSht.Range("A2").Value = "2"
    XLSSht.Range("B1").Value = "1"
    XLSSht.Range("B2").Value = "2"


    'create chart
    Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart
    Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
    Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim chartRange As Excel.Range

    xlCharts = XLSSht.ChartObjects
    myChart = xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250)
    chartPage = myChart.Chart
    chartRange = XLSSht.Range("A1", "B2")
    chartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
    chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to have a the chart display in the app in vb.net not excel. I have excel files with data that I want the app to pull from and display the data from excel in a chart in the vb.net app. Sorry if I wasn't clear. Thank you for you answer though, your code did work correctly. Just not what I was looking for.

Comment: It sounds like you are going to need a com control.  Under references/com I have about 30 for Office and am not willing to go in and try each of them to see if they offer the chart, and search for chart does not find anything.  This here seems to offer a char control: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422 to download, yet I have not downloaded it.  It should not be too hard to use, you should be able to download and install it, then find it under references/com and then just drag and drop in onto a form.